# How can I get Facebook videos to play in Epihany?

Tags: video-playback

Videos do not play on Facebook when using Epiphany. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Videos will not play. Install Firefox `sudo apt install firefox`, Chrome or Chromium and get rid of this browser by typing in terminal `sudo apt remove --purge epiphany`

Comment: The most funny fact is that developers are using Firefox or other browsers, but they put this nonsense browser into Elementary. Have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Epiphany actually don't support MSE and VP9 codecs which is necessary to play YouTube videos. Probably that is why it does not support videos on Facebook.